# JS: Array.map don't add to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have some data I'd like to transform using `Array.prototype.map`. However in the map function there is a chance of an error being thrown by an external function call.  I'd like to catch this error and not add that particular object to the returned array.  Currently I'm just returning undefined and then using `Array.prototype.filter` to clear out the undefined values, but this seems like a dirty way to do it.

To clarify, I'm looking for this functionality:

```
['apple','pear','banana', 'peach'].map(function(fruit){
     if (fruit === 'apple') {
         return undefined;
     }
     return 'I love to eat ' + fruit;
});
// ['I love to eat pear', 'I love to eat peach', 'I love to eat banana']
```

Any existing implementatons of this? Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Your link is to the jQuery `.map()` method, not the Javascript method.

Answer (score 17):

A more readable way would be;

```
['apple','pear','banana', 'peach'].filter(function(fruit) {
    return fruit === 'apple';
}).map(function(fruit) {
    return 'I love eating ' + fruit; 
})
```

With arrow functions & template strings;

```
['apple','pear','banana', 'peach']
    .filter(fruit => fruit === 'apple')
    .map(fruit => `I love eating ${fruit}`)
```

Comment: Ahh I like this way better. Using the filter before the map separates the actions into much clearer pieces.  thanks!

edit: @Barmar is right - although this is a cleaner way, it doesn't suit my exact use case for now.  I may accept this anyway because it works for other times where I've had this readability issue

Comment: While this will work for his example code, it doesn't seem like it will work for the real thing. He says he's calling a function that can report an error, and that's the case he wants to filter out.

Comment: @JasonMarmon Can you check for the error before calling the function in `.map()`?

Comment: I hope this helps, if you can provide any further code in what is causing the error I think I might be able to edit my answer!

Comment: If the OP is making an asynchronous external call then I don't think using that using `.map` and `.filter` is the proper way to go. If this is the case I suggest having a look at the [async library](http://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: @renatoargh it isn't an async call. Barmar - I can check for the error but it would end up looking messier and not being the implementation I'm going for.  I'm going to wrap the `map` and `filter` into a method on `Array.prototype` and close this Q

Comment: Nice solution, but shouldn't your filter test be fruit !== 'apple' to get the output the OP is asking for?

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use simple `for` loop, then instead of `map` try to use `reduce` this way:

```js
var result = ['apple','pear','banana', 'peach'].reduce(function(prev, curr){
     if (curr === 'apple') {
         return prev;
     }
     prev.push(curr);
     return prev;
}, []);

alert(result);
```

So the idea is that in case of "exception" you simply return `prev` array without modifying it.

Comment: Very clever use of `reduce`. It's possible, of course, to modify the code so that push is done only if some condition is true, leaving just a single `return prev`, but that's a minor nitpick. )

Comment: This is indeed a clever use of reduce, but it's not simpler to understand or easier to read than just filtering imo

Comment: Yes, probably. However I would personally go with `for/forEach` way.

Comment: I disagree. It's better than creating another method in Array.prototype, and it's quite concise. As this piece of code most probably should be encapsulated in a separate function _in the model_, I really feel there's nothing wrong with using what language gives us.

Comment: This code snippet can actually be reduced even further. Always avoid pushing into array if you can imo.


   var result = ['apple','pear','banana', 'peach'].reduce(function(prev, curr){
       if (curr === 'apple') {
         return prev;
       }
       return prev.concat(curr);
      }, []);
[/code]

Answer (score 3):

I ended up merging the two methods together into one on the `Array` prototype.  As @Benmj mentioned, you could alternatively put this in a custom utility lib.

```
Array.prototype.mapDefinedValues = function(handler) {
  return this.map(function(item){
    return handler(item);
   }).filter(function(item){
    return item !== undefined;
   });
}
```

Comment: Filtering before you map would remove unnecessary elements before mapping them, thereby reducing the number of elements you need to map.

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla's MDN for Array.prototype.map() says to use **forEach** or **for-of** for that:

> Since map builds a new array, using it when you aren't using the returned array is an
> anti-pattern; use forEach or for-of instead.
>
> You shouldn't be using map if:
>
> you're not using the array it returns; and/or
> **you're not returning a value from the callback**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#When_not_to_use_map

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the comments, you should combine this with a filter. Luckily, this is easy because you can chain array methods:

```
['apple','pear','banana', 'peach'].map(function(fruit){
     if (fruit === 'apple') {
         return undefined;
     }
     return 'I love to eat ' + fruit;
}).filter(function (item) { return item; });
```

### update

One of the tenants of functional programming like this is that you create simple building blocks that do not have side effects. What the OP is describing is essentially adding a side-effect to `.map`, and this type of behavior should be discouraged.

Comment: He said this is what he's currently doing.

Comment: So he did. He also said it "feels dirty." It shouldn't. :)

Comment: good point. this is what map should do. instead I'm going to implement a new method on `Array.prototype` that automagically combines the two

Comment: As a matter of style, I tend to avoid adding methods to the built-in prototypes. (Many people have said this before, Crockford being one) Instead, I create my own "underscore-like" utility library for functional programming on a per-project basis.

Comment: But your general approach of making a new function composed of existing ones is totally solid.

Comment: @Benmj @jtmarmon This would be even more readable: 
```.map(toSomething).filter(outUndefined)``` if you define ```toSomething``` and ```outUndefined``` as functions separately somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above can be reduced even further.

This code snippet can actually be reduced even further. Always avoid pushing into array if you can imo.

```
var result = ['apple','pear','banana', 'peach'].reduce(function(prev, curr){
   if (curr === 'apple') {
     return prev;
   }
   return prev.concat(curr);
  }, []);
```